# What is the best project structure for a project, that will be written in Kivy framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, architecture, kivy

I would like to use Kivy framework for developing a desktop application. So I wonder what would be the best approach to come up with in terms of arranging structure/architecture of the project. What are best practice for e.g. naming/splitting modules etc.